# Multiple input file handling

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this input

```
<form action="<?=isset($_GET['tree'])?'edit.php':'save.php'?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="<?=isset($_GET['tree'])?'edit-form':'csv-form'?>">
 ....
 .....
<input type="file" name="doc" id="doc" multiple>
```

I'm trying to handle the uploaded files but with

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

$_FILES only contains the last selected file.

Comment: `<input type="file" name="doc[]" > <input type="file" name="doc[]" > ...`

Comment: You need to define your input names as an array (see comment above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the name tag with square brackets: 
`<input type="file" name="doc[]" id="doc" multiple>`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
<input type="file" id="doc" name="doc[]" multiple>
```